# Github and private channel

Tags: bash

i tried to execute this bash command:

```
verweb=`sudo wget -q -O- 'https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/latest' | grep -o 'https[^\"]*' | grep tag | grep -o -P '(?<=tag/v).*(?=&quot;,)' | uniq` ; echo $verweb
```

and the output is correct: `3.23.4`

But when I execute this command there is no output:

```
url=`sudo wget -q -O- 'https://github.com/meetfranz/franz/releases/latest' | grep -o 'meetfranz[^\"]*' | grep amd64.deb | head -1` ; echo $url
```

this is because the github channel have private assets, can you help me to solve this problem? i know exists some API to fix this problem, but i don't know how use it:

https://github.com/wyozi/download-gh-release-asset/blob/master/download-asset

https://gist.github.com/maxim/6e15aa45ba010ab030c4#file-gh-dl-release

THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with a "private channel" (whatever that is).  I think it's just that this project has many artifacts per release so sometimes it doesn't inline all the release the HTML response and instead the list of release artifacts is getting lazily loaded via another request.

If you're trying to get the version latest release you can use something like:

```
gh release view -R meetfranz/franz --json name -q .name
5.9.2
```

Or using curl + jq:

```
curl -sSH "Accept: application/json" \
    -L https://github.com/meetfranz/franz/releases/latest \
  | jq -r .tag_name \
  | tail -c '+2'
5.9.2
```

Or if you're looking to get the download URL for the amd64 deb associated with the most recent release:

```
gh release view \
  -R meetfranz/franz \
  --json assets \
  -q '.assets[] | select( .url | contains("amd64.deb") ) | .url'
https://github.com/meetfranz/franz/releases/download/v5.9.2/franz_5.9.2_amd64.deb
```